# What does d^2 mean in the second derivative notation?

Tags: derivatives, physics

I was working through a physics problem today and ended up having to look up the answer because I got stuck. I noticed that the way I worked it was a bit different from the way the textbook worked it, and am curious to know if the method I used is mathematically valid. (Not sure if this belongs in the physics or math section, so my apologies if it is in the wrong one.)

For some context, the problem statement provided numerical values for $P_{av}$ (time-averaged power), $m$ (mass) and $d$ (distance).

Where the textbook and I agree:

$$P_{rad} = \frac{I}{c}$$
$$F = P_{rad}A = \frac{IA}{c} = \frac{P_{av}}{c} = ma_x$$
$$\frac{P_{av}}{mc} = a_x$$

Where the textbook and I diverge:

---

My Solution:

$$a_x = \frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$v = \frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$a_x = \frac{d\frac{dx}{dt}}{dt} = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{P_{av}}{mc}$$
$$dt^2 =d^2x\frac{mc}{P_{av}}$$
$$t = \sqrt{d^2x\frac{mc}{P_{av}}}$$

---

Textbook Solution: (assuming acceleration is constant)

$$x-x_0 = v_{0x}t + \frac{1}{2}a_xt^2$$
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2(x-x_0)}{a_x}}$$
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2(x-x_0)}{\frac{P_{av}}{mc}}}$$
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2(x-x_0)mc}{P_{av}}}$$

Does my answer assume acceleration is constant?
Is $d^2$ actually equal to $2(x-x_0)$?

Comment: You are using the derivative operator as a fraction - generally this is a bad idea. Worse still, you seem to be treating the $d$ as a number. This is not the case. The operator is $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. You cannot move this around like a fraction. $d$ is not a number, $d$ by itself is meaningless. So it makes no sense to say $d^2=2(x-x_0)$. (By the way, well done on writing a good first question, and including your working :) )

Comment: d²y/dx² is the second derivative of y in terms of x. There is absolutely no exponentiation discussed here. Taking the square root to get rid of the ² is not going to work